# get the name of a member of named vector cycled in `for`

Tags: r

I have a named vector: `myvec <- c(a='aaa', b='bbb', c='ccc')` and I process it with `for`:

```
for (memb in myvec){
 cat(memb, '\n');
}
```

This works fine, but what if I want to get the names in the same cycle, something like that:

```
for (memb in myvec){
 cat(name(memb)); # something for `name()`
 cat(': ', memb, '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you couldn't loop using the index of `myvec`?

```
myvec <- c(a='aaa', b='bbb', c='ccc', b='ddd')

for(i in 1:length(myvec)){
    cat(names(myvec)[i])
    cat(': ', myvec[i], '\n')
}
```

Comment: yes, that's another workaround I came to; I'm using this solution now. But I'm still wondering if I could get the names in a cycle...

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on what you do with duplicates. Here's my simple solution:

```
myvec <- c(a='aaa', b='bbb', c='ccc',d='bbb')
for (memb in myvec){
  cat(names(myvec[myvec==memb])); # returns all names of the value
  cat(': ', memb, '\n');
}
```

Output:

```
a:  aaa 
b d:  bbb 
c:  ccc 
b d:  bbb
```